# C++ 20 unordered_set library method for difference, intersection and union?

Tags: c++, c++20, unordered-set

I have seen some similar questions, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48158811/c-library-method-for-intersection-of-two-unordered-set), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47901339/unordered-set-intersection-in-c?rq=3) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/896155/tr1unordered-set-union-and-intersection), however they all are quite old and might be obsolete.

It is 2023 and the latest C++ standard is C++20 which was published in 2020, and different standards of C++ are very different.

So in C++20 are there library methods for set difference, intersection and union of ***`unordered_set`*** that was included using `#include <unordered_set>`?

I know in Python, if `a` and `b` are `set`s, `a & b` is the intersection, `a - b` is one way difference (elements in `a` that are not in `b`), `a ^ b` is the symmetric difference, `a | b` is the union. Are there similar methods in C++ that are more efficient than for loop based solutions?

I am reading [this](https://runestone.academy/ns/books/published/cpp4python/CollectionData/UnorderedSet.html?mode=browsing) and there seems to be `set_union`, `set_difference` and `set_intersection` methods, but I don't know what those are.

Of course I know how to brute force it:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_set>

using intSet = std::unordered_set<int>;

void print_set(const intSet& set) {
    std::cout << "{";
    for (int i : set) {
        std::cout << i << ", ";
    }
    std::cout << "}\n";
}

int main()
{
    intSet a = { 16, 1, 14, 7, 18, 5, 12, 19 };
    intSet b = { 0, 9, 1, 8, 19, 2, 18, 13 };
    intSet intersection_set;
    intSet diff_set;
    intSet union_set;
    for (int i : a) {
        if (b.count(i)) {
            intersection_set.insert(i);
        } else {
            diff_set.insert(i);
        }
        union_set.insert(i);
    }
    for (int i : b) {
        union_set.insert(i);
    }
    std::cout << "a = ";
    print_set(a);
    std::cout << "b = ";
    print_set(b);
    std::cout << "a & b = ";
    print_set(intersection_set);
    std::cout << "a - b = ";
    print_set(diff_set);
    std::cout << "a | b = ";
    print_set(union_set);
}
```

```
a = {16, 1, 14, 7, 18, 5, 12, 19, }
b = {8, 0, 1, 9, 19, 18, 2, 13, }
a & b = {1, 18, 19, }
a - b = {16, 14, 7, 5, 12, }
a | b = {16, 1, 14, 7, 18, 5, 12, 19, 8, 0, 9, 2, 13, }
```

Comment: The Python article just seems wrong, as in C++ an `unordered_set` is very different from a `set`. The set algorithms have a precondition that the sets are ordered, which the `unordered_set` obviously is not.

Comment: You say, *more efficient than for loop based solutions* ... but what makes you think, if such methods were implemented for **unordered** sets, that they wouldn't be (of necessity) loop-based?

Comment: You won't get much better than your "brute force" method. For the intersection, you can iterate over the smaller set, but that is all you can do when dealing with *unordered* sets.

Comment: Maybe you could implement `&`, `|` and others for unordered (and even ordered) sets and offer them to the Standards Committee for release in C++26?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The algorithms from `<algorithm>` aren't designed to work with `std::unordered_set` but with ordered ranges. For `std::unordered_set`, you can use its member functions in order to compute unions and differences, and `std::erase_if` for intersections.

#### In-place

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>

std::unordered_set<int> a, b; // TODO: fill with data

// a | b  (set union)
a.insert(b.begin(), b.end());
// better alternative if you are allowed to modify a AND b
a.merge(b);

// a - b  (set difference)
a.erase(b.begin(), b.end());

// a & b  (set intersection)
std::erase_if(a, [&b](int e) {
    return !b.contains(e);
});
```

#### Non-modifying

```cpp
#include <unordered_set>
#include <ranges>

const std::unordered_set<int> a, b; // TODO: fill with data

// a | b  (set union)
auto ab = {a, b};
auto joined = ab | std::views::join;
std::unordered_set<int> u(joined.begin(), joined.end());

// a - b  (set difference)
auto diff = a | std::views::filter([&b](int e) {
    return !b.contains(e);
});
std::unordered_set<int> d(diff.begin(), diff.end());

// a & b  (set intersection)
auto isect = a | std::views::filter([&b](int e) {
    return b.contains(e);
});
std::unordered_set<int> i(isect.begin(), isect.end());
```

*Note: these declarations can be simplified in C++23 with `std::from_range`.*